# How to draw a flat check box on the parent check box using its paint event in a winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, paintevent

The size of check boxes in my winform application doesn't increase automatically when a user increases the DPI of display.Only the size of text displayed alongside the check box increases.To fix this problem I tried to draw a custom check box over the parent check box, using its paint event.I am using the following command.
`ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc,chkBx.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);` The problem is that this creates a 3D box.But I want to draw a flat check box.How shall I achieve this?

Comment: WinForms can support Windows' high-DPI modes, but you have to configure it specially - but I advise against trying to reimplement built-in controls just for rendering issues. Have you looked at the form scaling properties?

Comment: You didnt mention, so, is the FlatStyle set to flat? Failing that, rather than use the controlpaint, you could just draw out what you need, so a box for the checkbox with check or not, and its label.

Comment: I have already set the autoscale mode to DPI. But it increases the bounds for the checkbox and not the size of check box itself.That is why I am trying to draw the checkbox with required size myself.

Comment: I have set the property flatstyle to flat.

Comment: Use the CheckBoxRenderer class.

Comment: That class also doesn't have any method to draw a flat check box.